# How to get Workday External Learning User Accounts using WQL

Tags: workday-api

I want to get all the **workday External Learning User Account using wql** or from soap request.

I had made a copy of **"All Workday Accounts" report** but i am not able to differentiate between other workday account and the External Learning User Account. How can i get only External Learning User Account using WQL?

Also i had tried to get the workday External Learning User Account using "**Get_Workday_Account_Request**" but it is throwing an below error

Request -

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bsvc="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
       <soapenv:Body>
      <bsvc:Get_Workday_Account_Request>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <bsvc:Request_References>
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
            <bsvc:Workday_Account_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="string">
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="External_Learning_User_ID">EXTERNAL_LEARNING_USER-6-5</bsvc:ID>
            </bsvc:Workday_Account_Reference>
         </bsvc:Request_References>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <bsvc:Request_Criteria/>
      </bsvc:Get_Workday_Account_Request>    </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response -

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client.validationError</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Validation error occurred. The entered information does not meet the restrictions defined for this field. (Workday_Account_Reference).</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <wd:Validation_Fault>
               <wd:Validation_Error>
                  <wd:Message>The entered information does not meet the restrictions defined for this field. (Workday_Account_Reference).</wd:Message>
                  <wd:Detail_Message>The entered information does not meet the restrictions defined for this field. (Workday_Account_Reference).</wd:Detail_Message>
                  <wd:Xpath>/wd:Get_Workday_Account_Request[1]/wd:Request_References[1]/wd:Workday_Account_Reference</wd:Xpath>
               </wd:Validation_Error>
            </wd:Validation_Fault>
         </detail>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could let me know how to retrieve the external learning user accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Get_External_Learning_Users API.